# error al usar phpMailer

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo con *phpMailer*, agrego los datos que piden(correos,contraseñas), al momento de abrir el archivo `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/enviar.php` en el navegador solo me muestra el código php y al abrirlo desde localhost (`http://localhost/enviar.php`) me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "phpmailer\PHPMailer" not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\enviar.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\enviar.php on line 8

este es el codigo que tengo

```
    <?php
    use  phpmailer\PHPMailer;
    use  phpmailer\SMTP;
    use  phpmailer\Exception;

 
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      //Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'smtp.example.com';                     //SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               //SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Asunto';
        $mail->Body    = 'Correo de prueba';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'El mensaje se envio correctamente';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
?>
```

Otra cosa es que estoy usando xampp, al terminar la instalacion y abrir el documento index.php de la carpeta htdocs me dio el siguien mensaje de error

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

pero al abrir el `http://localhost/dashboard/` y otros documentos  abren correctamente.

Comment: Dond estas cargando el autoload del PHPMailer?

Comment: Mm si es un archivo de la carpeta phpmailer , no me aparece ningún archivo con ese nombre y no lo estoy cargando

Comment: [Revisa el ejemplo oficial en Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example), verás que después de los `use` debes incluir el `autoload.php` indicando en qué carpeta está, suele ser en la carpeta `vendor`, la cuestión es que la ruta que pongas ahí debe ser válida. Supongo que habrás instalado PHPMailer correctamente.

Comment: si, el archivo autoload.php esta en la carpeta phpMyAdmin/vendor/, estoy usando xampp y los archivos los tengo en la carpeta htdocs, y accedo al autoload.php (../phpMyAdmin/vendor/autoload.php), igual ya tengo los archivos PHPMailer, SMTP, Exception en una carpeta donde los mando a llamar pero me da el siguiente error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPMailer\PHPMailer" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\enviar.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\enviar.php on line 12, al agregar la carpeta vendor al htdocs, igual me marca el error.